# Error while trying to send logs with rsyslog without local storage

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I'm trying to send logs into datadog using rsyslog. Ideally, I'm trying to do this without having the logs stored on the server hosting rsyslog. I've run into an error in my config that I haven't been able to find out much about. The error occurs on startup of rsyslog.

`omfwd: could not get addrinfo for hostname '(null)':'(null)': Name or service not known [v8.2001.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]`

Here's the portion I've added into the default rsyslog.config

```
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="datadog")

ruleset(name="datadog"){
    action(
        type="omfwd" 
        action.resumeRetryCount="-1" 
        queue.type="linkedList" 
        queue.saveOnShutdown="on" 
        queue.maxDiskSpace="1g" 
        queue.fileName="fwdRule1"
)

$template DatadogFormat,"00000000000000000 <%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% - - - %msg%\n "

$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
$ActionSendStreamDriver gtls
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name

$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer *.logs.datadoghq.com
    *.* @@intake.logs.datadoghq.com:10516;DatadogFormat
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first.

The module `imudp` enables log **reception** over udp.

The module `omfwd` enables log **forwarding** over (tcp, udp, ...)

---

So most probably - or atleast as far as i can tell - with rsyslog you just want to log messages locally and then send them to datadog.

I don't know anything about the `$ActionSendStreamDriver` tags, so I can't help you there. But what is jumping out is, that in your `action` you haven't defined where the logs should be sent to.

```
ruleset(name="datadog"){
    action(
        type="omfwd"
        target="10.100.1.1"
        port="514"
        protocol="udp"
        ...
    )
    ...
}
```